# Display queries in access subform from a selected listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Within Access 2010, I am trying to make a form display a query within a subform `QueriesSubForm` that when selected from listbox `QueryListBox` and then click on the button `runbtn`. It is supposed to display the query within the linked subform, and change when you do this whole steps again from a different choice selected on the listbox and click on the button.

At the moment I can only get it to work, if I want it to display the queries in a new task window, when programmed like so:

QueriesListBox Listbox - SQL View

```
SELECT MSysObjects.[Name]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.[Type])=5) AND ((Left([Name],1))<>"~"))
ORDER BY MSysObjects.[Name];
```

runbtn Button - VBA View

```
Private Sub runbtn_Click()
DoCmd.OpenQuery QueryListBox, acViewNormal
End Sub
```

It works and appears to just open one of the queries from the queries list and display it to me, which I do not want.

This might be an easy thing, but I can not see how it is done with either SQL, VBA or Macro, which I am guessing is need for this to work

Comment: How many different queries do you have? Do you think you'll need to be adding in more queries? I can think of one option that might work, but it wouldn't be very scalable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's one way to do it. First make sure your subform is set up with no source object. Then setup your button click like so:

```
Private Sub runbtn_Click()
    Me.QueriesSubForm.SourceObject = "Query." & QueryListBox.Value
End Sub
```

That should get you the result you're looking for. Alternatively, if you want your form to open with a certain query to displayed on open, you could set up your subform's source object to that query. Using the properties window find the source object drop down and find the query you want to show when the form opens.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp, I always `.Requery` just to be safe, a bad habit perhaps. Edited to remove `.Requery` anyway

Comment: Yeah, perhaps an extra `.Requery` doesn't hurt in general.  You should definitely try to avoid it for a big honker of a query on a busy db server.  The DBAs would hunt you down and beat you with big sticks.  No fun.

Comment: Haha yes I think it's definitely a habit worthy of dropping.